# Can we pass Java Pojo to Elasticsearch Index API using new REST Client

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-rest-client

I am going through the new Elasticsearch's Java REST client and looking at different ways to index a document ( here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/7.3/java-rest-high-document-index.html )

Is there any possibility where I can pass my Java Pojo to Index? like following

```
IndexRequest request = new IndexRequest("posts"); 
request.id("1"); 
request.source(new User("1", "Foo", 22, new Date()));
IndexResponse indexResponse = client.index(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot pass a POJO directly to the `IndexRequest.source()` method, you need to either pass:

1. a [JSON string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-docs-index.html#java-docs-index-generate-diy)
2. a [Map](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-docs-index.html#java-docs-index-generate-using-map)
3. a [Jackson serialized POJO](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-docs-index.html#java-docs-index-generate-beans)
4. an object created via a [provided helper](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-docs-index.html#java-docs-index-generate-helpers)

In your case, I guess the 3rd option could make more sense since you have a POJO at hand.

Comment: Is this the same behaviour with the transport client too?

Comment: Yes same behavior

Answer (score 0):

If you are using RestHighLevelClient version 7.x, you can pass a POJO with simple mapping like:

```
IndexRequest request = new IndexRequest("posts");
request.id("1");
request.source(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(new User("1", "Foo", 22, new Date())), XContentType.JSON);
IndexResponse indexResponse = client.index(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```